Sequential projection onto circumferences
Let $S = (s_1, \dots, s_n) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ be a sequence of euclidean spheres,
where

$s_k = \{ x : \| c_k - x \|^2_2 \leqslant r_k^2\} \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is the sphere $s_k \in S$ space, $\forall k \in \{1, \dots, n\}$;
$c_k \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is the sphere $s_k$ center, $\forall k \in \{1, \dots, n\}$; And
$r_k \geqslant 0$ is the sphere $s_k$ radius, $\forall k \in \{1, \dots, n\}$.

We name as a tour of $S$ a sequence of points $P = (p_1, \dots, p_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, such that $p_k$ belongs to the closure of sphere $s_k \in S$, i.e. $\| c_k - p_k \|_2 \ni r_k$, $\forall k \in \{1, \dots, n\}$. For instance, the figure below presents an example of $S$ and one of its respective tour $P$.

We name as the distance between two points $p_j$ and $p_k$ as $d(p_j, p_k) =$ abs$(\| p_n - p_1 \|_2)$.
And we say that the cost of a tour is given by the sequential sum of the lengths of its segments, i.e. $\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} d(p_k, p_{k + 1}) + d(p_n, p_1)$. For instance, in the above example, the resulting cost is given by $d(p_1, p_2) + d(p_2, p_3) + d(p_3, p_4) + d(p_4, p_1)$.
My question is: how can we find the minimum cost tour $P$ of a spheres sequence $S$?
The only solution that comes to my mind is to model an NLP, as presented below.
For simplicity, I am ignoring reformulations for acquiring smoothness and convexities.
$\min \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} d(p_k, p_{k + 1}) + d(p_n, p_1)$
s.t.

$\|c_k - p_k \|_2 \ni r_k$, $\forall k \in \{1, \dots, n\}$; And
$p \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$.

However, I was looking for some analytical strategy, which does not delegate the reponsability to an NLP solver, at least not entirely, maybe at most solving subproblems by means of some NLP tasks.
PS.: If some answer for $m = 2$, I would be extremely satisfied.
